# Node.JS + LDAPjs = зависания

Tags: node.js

Есть классический сервер на Node.JS, который формирует запросы на LDAP через LDAPjs , проблема в том что если сделать много запросов подряд, ну скажем 30-40, то Node.JS зависает, то есть в консоле видно что он начинает обрабатывать запросы с задержкой в несколько минут, выполнит 3-5 запросов и висит, сначала грешил на LDAPjs , но потом заметил что и статика тоже не отдаётся, то есть весь сервер лежит, тк до LDAPjs таких проблем небыло, есть ещё поиск по JSON и он работает стабильно на достаточно большом кол-ве запросов, то явно дело в самом Node.JS, единственное что приходит на ум так это то что LDAPjs превышает какой-то порог использования ресурсов в самом Node.JS
ps : после ряда эксперементов выяснилось , если фу-цию запускать в цикле for то она отрабатывает на ура по 100 запросов, но как только я делаю запрос через web морду всё падает, тестовый код почищенный вот

```
/*jslint node: true, plusplus: true, vars: true*/
'use strict';
var fs = require("fs");
var http = require("http");
var path = require("path");
var url = require('url');
var util = require('util');
var ldap = require('ldapjs');

var pbdb_index = fs.readFileSync('./index.html');
var jquery = fs.readFileSync('./jquery.js');
var server_port = '80';



http.createServer(function (req, res) {
    if (req.method !== undefined && (req.method).toString() === "POST") {
        var body = '';
        req.on('data', function (data) {
            body += data;
        });
        req.on('end', function () {
            var body_arr = decodeURIComponent(body);
            body_arr = body_arr.replace(/[+]/gi, " ").split('=');
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
            if (req.url === "/ldap" && body_arr[1].length > 2) {
                search_in_LDAP(body_arr[0], body_arr[1], function (err, ret_array) {
                    ret_array = ret_array.toString();
                    res.end(ret_array);
                }
                              );
            }
        });
    }
    if (req.method !== undefined && (req.method).toString() === "GET") {
        if (url.parse(req.url).pathname === '/jquery.js') {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/javasript'});
            res.end(jquery);
        } else {
            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=utf8'});
            res.end(pbdb_index);
        }
    }
}).listen(server_port);



function search_in_LDAP(attribute_id1, search_str, callback) {
    var client = ldap.createClient({
        url: 'ldap://10.0.0.1:389/DC=domainname,DC=ru'
    });
    var ldap_user = 'login';
    var ldap_pass = 'password';
    var ret_array = [];
    var attribute_id = "sn";
    var opts = {
        filter: "(&(" + attribute_id + "=" + search_str + "*))",
        scope: "sub"
    };
    client.bind(ldap_user, ldap_pass, function (err, res) {
        if (err) {
            console.log("ERROR: bind error" + err);
            return 1;
        }
        client.search('OU=OU_Name,DC=domainname,DC=ru', opts, function (err, search) {
            search.on('searchEntry', function (entry) {
                var user = entry.object;
                var tem_json_obj = {};
                tem_json_obj.sn = entry.object.sn || "";
                tem_json_obj.cn = entry.object.cn || "";
                tem_json_obj.mail = entry.object.mail || "";
                tem_json_obj.department = entry.object.department || "";
                tem_json_obj.description = entry.object.description || "";
                tem_json_obj.physicalDeliveryOfficeName = entry.object.physicalDeliveryOfficeName || "";
                tem_json_obj.title = entry.object.title || "";
                tem_json_obj.telephoneNumber = entry.object.telephoneNumber || "";
                tem_json_obj.distinguishedName = entry.object.distinguishedName || "";
                ret_array.push(tem_json_obj);
            });
            search.on('end', function (err) {
                client.unbind(function (err, data) {
                    callback(err, ret_array);
                });
            });
        });
    });
}



function strip_string_gi(in_str, regexp_str) {
    var regexp_key = "gi";
    var out_str = [];
    if (typeof in_str === 'string') {
        var reg_exp = new RegExp(regexp_str, regexp_key);
        out_str = in_str.match(reg_exp);
        if (out_str !== null && out_str.length > 0) {
            out_str = out_str.join('');
            return out_str;
        }
    }
    console.log("strip_string function ERROR:\n" + in_str + "\n" + regexp_str);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Скорее, запросы в LDAP пытаются какую-то часть сделать синхронно и всё их ждёт. Джаваскриптовый код ведь в одном потоке выполняется.

Comment: ну тогда почему не сразу а через 50 запросов, и почему висит так долго, минут за 30 не отвисло, более того с опцией debug оно вобще через 20 минут выдало что процесс завершён и всё

Comment: вобщем теперь он залипает почти сразу, уже после нескольких вводов поиска, с каждым разом меня Node всё больше расстраивает :(

Comment: Подозревал винду, но на чистой виртуалке всё то-же самое, видать проблема в глубине ноды кроется, потому что сам поиск в LDAPjs  асинхронный и если он валит всю ноду то это получается баг самой ноды

Comment: Хоть бы код показали что за модулями пользуешься.

Comment: модуль только LDAPjs . сейчас почищу код от лишнего, чтобы осталась только связка LDAPjs-Web и буду тестить, но пока всё сводится либо к багу ноду, либо к багу ноды+багу LDAPjs, потому как LDAPjs асинхронный но вешает всю ноду намертво, это явно ненормально

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1) Возможно у Вас не всегда выполняется это условие

```
if (req.url === "/ldap" && body_arr[1].length > 2)
```

и как следствие, Вы не закрываете соединение `res.end`

так же нет закрытия соединения на

```
if (req.method !== undefined && (req.method).toString() === "POST") {
```

клиент может посладть запрос типа OPTIONS, DELETE, и т.п. и у Вас зависнет соединение до таймаута

2) обновите Ноду

Comment: Спасибо , пролюбил res.end, хотя странно что нода на это так отреагировала , видимо глубоко в кишках она некорректно отрабатывает такое событие